# How can I wirelessly scan with a Canon MF642C on Windows 10?

Tags: network-printer

How the heck do I wirelessly scan on Windows 10 64bit with [this Canon (MF642Cdw)](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/printers/color-laser/canon-color-imageclass-mf642cdw) multi-function device!?!

Steps taken:

- I've read the manual--the included paper version and also 30min of the 700pg PDF.
- I've updated the firmware.
- I've installed **[Windows 64bit] MF644Cdw/MF642Cdw MFDrivers (Generic Plus UFR II / Generic FAX / ScanGear)**
- I've installed **[Windows 32bit & 64bit] MF Scan Utility Ver.1.9.0.0**
- I've ensured that it's on the local network and wirelessly scans to every Apple computer in the house, EVEN WITHOUT INSTALLING DRIVERS.
- I've ensured that it can wirelessly PRINT from Windows 10 (every Windows 10 machine in the house)
- I've accessed the browser-based admin interface and gone through almost every page of settings and filled in missing info like device name, scanning subjectline, etc.
- I've tried scanning to email from the device itself and I'm told to go to the browser interface to complete the setup.
- I've tried adding the thing as a scanner through the "add new device" interface but Windows isn't seeing anything new.
- I've tried scanning through Canon's "MF Scan Utility" software but it isn't seeing it unless plugged in by USB cable.
- I've tried scanning through Microsoft's "Scan" app but that doesn't see it either, unless plugged in by a USB cable.

I'm seriously at my wit's end. What's the next step?

Comment: On this Canon page there is a patch for Network Scanning  Work through this page and see if the drivers / patch help you:  https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/color-laser/mf624cw?tab=drivers_downloads

Comment: Dang... if the MF624Cw patch works on the MF642Cdw I'm going to read Canon the riot act. That's just nuts. Will try it out as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: I may have made a typo keying in your printer model. Apologies for that